# d3.js update bar chart labels after sorting data

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I can't seem to figure out how to update bar labels when I re-sort ranking data; essentially the label names will all remain the same, but their order will change.

Originally I have:

```
    // University Names
    labelsContainer = chart.append('g')
                           .attr('transform', 'translate(' + (uniLabel - barLabelPadding) + ',' + (gridLabelHeight + topMargin) + ')') 
                           .selectAll('text')
                           .data(sortedData)
                           .enter()
                           .append('text')
                           .attr('x', xoffset)
                           .attr('y', yText)
                           .attr('stroke', 'none')
                           .attr('fill', 'black')
                           .attr("dy", ".35em") // vertical-align: middle
                           .attr('text-anchor', 'end')
                           .text(barLabel);
```

I sort the data differently, which I still call sortedData. The rectangles and rest of the graph updates successfully...save for the labels (which I have on only one rectangle bar column.)

In a new function I tried:

```
        // update University Names (this overwrites, however... I want to select the existing label instead of appending text on top of the original text)
        labelsContainer = chart.append('g')
                               .attr('transform', 'translate(' + (uniLabel - barLabelPadding) + ',' + (gridLabelHeight + topMargin) + ')') 
                               .selectAll('text')
                               .data(sortedData)
                               .enter()              // using transition   ... or selecting the group ... does not allow the new text to appear!
                               .append('text')
                               .attr('x', xoffset)
                               .attr('y', yText)
                               .attr('stroke', 'none')
                               .attr('fill', 'black')
                               .attr("dy", ".35em") // vertical-align: middle
                               .attr('text-anchor', 'end')
                               .text(barLabel);
```

The issue here is that this just adds the new (correct) labels on top of the existing ones, instead of replacing them.

Using  transition() I'm able to update the rest of the graph, but not the labels.

Any ideas of how to fix? Happy to provide more info/context if need be...

UPDATE 12/24: JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/myhrvold/BVB2d/

JSFiddle showing transition, but with labels being overwritten: http://jsfiddle.net/myhrvold/BVB2d/embedded/result/

I know that by appending, I'm overwriting; but in attempting to replace, nothing happens and the original text remains, so the idea here is that I'm showing that I am at least generating the correct new labels and putting them in the right place...it's just that I'm not substituting them from my original labels...

Comment: can you put your code to jsfiddle to show the data

Comment: You are calling `chart.append('g')` before a `.selectAll('text')`, which selects `text` nodes in the new container. Try `chart.select('g')` instead to select the `g`. You may need to add more classes to make it uniquely idenfiable inside `chart` though: e.g. `g.univerity-labels-container`.

Comment: You have to use d3's  `update` selection while trying to update the labels. See this [link](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/join/) for a detailed write up of joins. You may also to have to specify a `key` function accessor while calling the [`.data()`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-data) method. If you need more help, paste a fiddle.

Comment: Have you seen [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3885705)?

Comment: Thanks everyone for comments. Yes, I did see the Sorted Bar example. JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/myhrvold/BVB2d/                                               JSFiddle w/ embedded results: http://jsfiddle.net/myhrvold/BVB2d/embedded/result/     I tried select instead of append, but that didn't work (maybe I'm not understanding what to do....)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're completely repeating your code when you update your data -- including the `chart.append('g')` which creates a new group and then adds text labels to it.  Because you've just created this as a new group, when you select inside it you can't select any of the labels you created the first time, so instead you end up creating all new labels.

To fix: first, as @musically_ut suggested, give each of your groups a unique class name.  Then, in your update method select this group and the text elements it contains using `chart.select(g.univerity-labels-container).selectAll("text")`.  However, you'll find you still have problems because you've got everything chained to an enter(); since you don't expect any new elements to be added when sorting, just take out that line. *

That should get it working, but the program is still painfully complex for what you're trying to do.  For starters, all of this could work a lot better as an HTML table which would handle a lot of the layout for you.  More importantly, you could save a lot of work if, instead of grouping elements by column you grouped them by row.  That way, you would only have to join the data once, to the group, instead of doing separate data joins for each variable.  If I have a chance in the next few days, I might try to write up a from-the-ground up explanations of how to approach this.  In the meantime, google "d3 sortable table" for a couple examples, or look at the source code for this [NYT graphic by Mike Bostock](http://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2013/09/24/us/health-care-premiums.html?_r=0).

*For updating with an `enter()` step, I find most tutorials don't describe the update process very clearly, but I wrote up a step-by-step breakdown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20688115/d3-js-circle-plotting-does-not-working-properly-while-trying-to-load-after-first/20754006#20754006) yesterday.

Comment: Thanks for this detailed explanation. I'm first trying to get to work, with just adding unique class name to labels container. I add: .attr("class", "univerity-labels-container") just below chart.append('g') for my original labels container.   Then, I add: chart.select(g.univerity-labels-container).selectAll("text")  to the labelsContainer in my sort_orig() function, while removing the enter() statement (and the selectAll("text") I had below). But I get an error: 'Uncaught ReferenceError: g is not defined' . Is this a scoping issue? Have toyed around with but can't get to work...

Comment: updated JFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/myhrvold/C99pP/2/ (note that the sort_orig() function doesn't work now, even though JSFiddle says that code is OK). Result: http://jsfiddle.net/myhrvold/C99pP/3/embedded/result/

Comment: Sorry, that was my error.  There should always be quotes around the selector, i.e.: `chart.select("g.univerity-labels-container").selectAll("text")`  The "g is not defined" error is usually a good sign that you've forgotten to put something in quotes, and javascript is looking for a variable of that name.

Comment: P.S.  I checked the fiddle, and you also still have a couple extra statements in that chain that you don't need: the translate statement was for when you created the entire group, you don't need it when re-selecting; and you definitely don't need an `append("text") since the text elements are already there.  With those three changes it looks good to me: http://jsfiddle.net/C99pP/5/

Comment: Thanks -- it works, and I tried most other quotation selections, but not with the g. before the label! Good to know about that error diagonsis in the future, and thanks also for explaining why I don't need some of the other statements as well; I'm still new to exactly what's necessary and what's not, so to make the code run I include as much info as possible even though in some instances it's extraneous...